# How to remove the bios password on a Lenovo laptop?

Tags: laptop, bios, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 12 laptop that has a bios password on it that I don't know. Can anyone give me a comprehensive list of ways that it can be reset/removed for my specific laptop? If anyone knows how to remove it that doesn't involve potential damage to my PC (like desoldering etc..) I would greatly appreciate it.

And btw this is a university issued laptop that is given free to all students. However since graduating I get to keep it. The university does not provide the bios password however which I need :/

Comment: If you were given a laptop during your studies and luckily for you got to keep it, then I assume you've used it for studies. How then you were able to login into BIOS without knowing login credentials? It doesn't matter if you're graduated from the university or not there still should be university IT support what issues these passwords. Go and talk to them.

Comment: @alljamin I never logged into the bios. The university set up everything on there. Now I would like to change some settings because I use this laptop on the go besides my desktop. And like I said they don't provide the password for whatever reason, I have tried asking them.